# AWS CLI put cloudwatch logs with a JSON in message

Tags: linux, bash, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am trying to put logs to AWS CloudWatch logs via AWS CLI using a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
EVENT_TIME=$(date +%s%3N)
LOG_LEVEL=6
EVENT_SOURCE=myapp
MESSAGE=1

OUTPUT=$(jq -n \
  --arg EventTime "$EVENT_TIME" \
  --arg LogLevel "$LOG_LEVEL" \
  --arg EventSource "$EVENT_SOURCE" \
  --arg Message "$MESSAGE" \
  '{EventTime:$EventTime,LogLevel:$LogLevel,EventSource:$EventSource,Message:$Message}')

MESSAGE="$OUTPUT"

aws logs put-log-events --log-group-name test --log-stream-name local --log-events timestamp=$(date +%s%3N),message=$MESSAGE
```

but I am getting error:

```
Error parsing parameter '--log-events': Expected: '<double quoted>', received: '<none>' 
for input:
 timestamp=1654692489664,message="{
```

The command works fine, if I remove the JSON message to a simple string. It should be an issue with quoting but not sure where the problem is. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message parameter needs to be a string containing the json, not the direct json created with jq.

Something like this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
EVENT_TIME=$(date +%s000)
LOG_LEVEL=6
EVENT_SOURCE=myapp
MESSAGE=1

OUTPUT=$(jq -n \
  --arg EventTime "$EVENT_TIME" \
  --arg LogLevel "$LOG_LEVEL" \
  --arg EventSource "$EVENT_SOURCE" \
  --arg Message "$MESSAGE" \
      '{EventTime:$EventTime,LogLevel:$LogLevel,EventSource:$EventSource,Message:$Message}')


LOG_MESSAGE=$(echo $OUTPUT | sed 's/"/\\"/g') 
   
aws logs put-log-events --log-group-name test --log-stream-name local --log-events timestamp=$(date +%s000),message=\""$LOG_MESSAGE"\"
```

Also, if you plan to use the `put-log-events` like this, you will need to provide the `--sequence-token` for consecutive puts. See here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/put-log-events.html

Might be best to setup CloudWatch agent to publish the logs.

Comment: Thanks for your great comment! Issue resolved by your code block suggestion. Also I am looking to use AWS CloudWatch agent. Thanks again.

Comment: Docs have been updated, looks like a sequence token is no longer necessary: 

> The sequence token is now ignored in PutLogEvents actions. PutLogEvents actions are always accepted and never return InvalidSequenceTokenException or DataAlreadyAcceptedException even if the sequence token is not valid. You can use parallel PutLogEvents actions on the same log stream.